py-click is disabled without click?
I'm new to Pyscript, I create an UI for password generation, yet the button is grayed out without clicking
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Password Generator</title>

        <!-- Recommended meta tags -->
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/releases/2024.7.1/core.css">
 
        <script type="module" src="https://pyscript.net/releases/2024.7.1/core.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Password Generator</h1>
        <p>Generate password with your key</p>
        <input type="text" id="seed" placeholder="Type keyword here..." />
        <input type="text" id="len" placeholder="Type length here..." />
        <button id="run" type="button" py-click="password_generation">Generate</button>
        <div id="output"></div>
        <script type="py" src="./main.py" config="./pyscript.toml" terminal></script>
    </body> </html>

I tried pys-onClick, but there is the same problem.
I appreciate your help

Even I have faced the same issue.It's not working when terminal is included inside the script tag.Try removing the terminal to enable the button.
Else you have the option of using @when decorator.Which works for both terminal and DOM.

For me the button is not grayed out.Refer to the following link https://_12.pyscriptapps.com/quiet-dawn/latest/
